# request not showing all headers nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, middleware

I am using nodejs with express. I have a middleware to check the authorization token sent through the headers in the request.

Previously, I was setting the middleware in each endpoint, one by one. Everything worked perfectly, the headers were correctly sent in the request. I'm doing it with authorization bearer, so in my auth middleware, I check if there's an "Authorization" header.

Now I moved the middleware to the server.js, to wrap all the routes, so I don't have to set it manually. There are some routes that are unprotected so I am excluding them from the middleware with the "unless" function.

```
const unless = function(path, middleware) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        let reqMethod = req.method;
        if(req.method == 'OPTIONS'){
            reqMethod = req.headers['access-control-request-method'];
        }
        if (path.find(({url,method,methods}) => url == req.path && (method==reqMethod || methods==reqMethod))) {
            next();
        } else {
            middleware(req, res, next);
        }
    };
};

app.use(schemaValidator,unless(publicPaths,auth),routes);
```

The "unless" method seems to work fine with the unprotected routes. The problem now is that, for some reason, I'm not getting the request headers as I used to. Instead of getting the "Authorization" header with the token, I'm just getting this:

"access-control-request-headers":"authorization".

And if I check for the req.headers.authorization it is undefined.

Side note: the publicPaths is an array of objects with the "URL" and "method" of the unprotected endpoints as the keys.

Does anyone know what might be happening? If you need any more information please tell me!

Comment: Do you have the req.headers before "middleware(req, res, next);" is called? What about before unless middleware ?

Comment: You appear to be attempting to write your own CORS pre-flight request handler. Why?

Comment: I'm checking it inside the middleware. but if i do a console.log(req.headers) before  the unless, the authorization bearer is also not there. i don't understand why @YatinGupta

Comment: @Phil my auth middleware is to check if the sent token is valid or not, the "unless" method is just to exclude the unprotected endpoints because there's no authorization header sent in those so it fails. maybe I'm writing my own CORS pre-flight request handler but it's not my intention, why do you say that I am doing that? thanks for the answer!

Comment: ps: it works if i try it with postman

Comment: If its working with postman are you sure you are sending the token through the client? can you console log the request headers before any middleware is called to confirm if code is removing it anywhere ?

Comment: I'm sure because if I inspect the request in the network tab on google inspect i see the authorization bearer in the headers. i tried what you said, i did another middleware before all the others with a console.log(req.headers) and it's not showing the authorization bearer.  @YatinGupta

Comment: if anyone sees this in the future: i was seeing the authorization bearer in the headers because i was checking the actual request, not the preflight. my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling preflight `OPTIONS` requests is an entirely separate concern to authorisation.

[Preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) typically will not have any `Authorisation` header present. I highly recommend using the industry standard [cors middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors), registered **before** any other request handling middleware

```js
const cors = require("cors");
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["https://example.com"],
};

const unless = function (path, middleware) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (
      paths.some(
        ({ url, method, methods }) =>
          url === req.path && (method === req.method || methods === req.method)
      )
    ) {
      next();
    } else {
      middleware(req, res, next);
    }
  };
};

app.use(schemaValidator, cors(corsOptions), unless(publicPaths, auth), routes);
```

This will take care of `OPTIONS` requests independently, leaving your middleware to work with actual requests.

---

You won't see any issues with Postman since it is not subject to the same-origin policy and will not send preflight `OPTIONS` requests.

Comment: ohh i see what you mean.. so I'm first getting a preflight request which doesn't have the authorization and then, if it passes the cors protocol, the request would go through the auth middleware. did i understand correclty?

Comment: @pop that's it exactly!